# I got an strage php syntax error

Tags: php, syntax

```
if(isset($_POST['contactname']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
$contactname = $_POST['contactname'];

$email = $_POST['email'];

$message = $_POST['message'];

$subject = "Ձեզ գրել են ձեր կայքից";

$to = "bulbulator2007@mail.ru";

$headers = "From: ".$email;
}
```

> [19-May-2013 04:57:16 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
> unexpected '{' in /home3/webex/public_html/mmm/mar/views/mail.php on
> line 1
>
> [19-May-2013 04:57:20 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
> unexpected '{' in /home3/webex/public_html/mmm/mar/views/mail.php on
> line 1
>
> [19-May-2013 04:57:25 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
> unexpected '{' in /home3/webex/public_html/mmm/mar/views/mail.php on
> line 1
>
> [19-May-2013 04:57:31 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
> unexpected '{' in /home3/webex/public_html/mmm/mar/views/mail.php on
> line 1
>
> [19-May-2013 04:57:36 America/Denver] PHP Parse error:  syntax error,
> unexpected '{' in /home3/webex/public_html/mmm/mar/views/mail.php on
> line 1

Whats the error problem?

Comment: http://codepad.org/6wiG5GAg    working

Comment: There must be some more code before this. May we see that?

Comment: Are you sure you copy-pasted it exactly, without any modifications?

Comment: No PHP start tag? Seems something's missing here. Also, is this run directly or included from somewhere?

Comment: there is no other code in that file, i have there php start tag

Comment: @Marker The thing is that `line 1` normally is the line with the start PHP tag...

Comment: yeah i know... i saved the file by notepad, the problem solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open another text editor and remove all the non ascii or non unicode chars that appeared there while (probably) copying code from Skype